# How to convert rows into column and join with table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I am working on a sales project where there are two tables. one is sales_rev_asset
and another is sales_lab.

Below are the table format:-


sales_rev_asset:-

`salesid year    rev_ratio1  rev_ratio_2 ratio_3 asset_ratio1    asset_ratio_2   asset_ratio_3
10001   2016    30  12  56  78  89  90
10001   2017    13  56  87  33  95  28
10001   2018    98  84  53  62  24  48
10002   2016    33  55  62  69  78  10
10002   2017    62  17  12  14  7   9
10002   2018    28  83  45  16  35  50`



sales_lab:-
`salesid    ratio_name  col1    col2    col3
10001   lab_ratio1  1   15  54
10001   lab_ratio2  3   54  41
10001   lab_ratio3  5   98  12
10002   lab_ratio1  2   74  23
10002   lab_ratio2  8   32  36
10002   lab_ratio3  9   19  65`



But i want the data like below format:-

`salesid year    rev_ratio1  rev_ratio_2 ratio_3 asset_ratio1    asset_ratio_2   asset_ratio_3   lab_ratio1  lab_ratio2  lab_ratio3
10001   2016    30  12  56  78  89  90  1   3   5
10001   2017    13  56  87  33  95  28  15  54  98
10001   2018    98  84  53  62  24  48  54  41  12
10002   2016    33  55  62  69  78  10  2   8   9
10002   2017    62  17  12  14  7   9   74  32  36
10002   2018    28  83  45  16  35  50  23  36  65`

Please someone suggest me.How can i achieve the above format in oracle. I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Look up pivoting.

Comment: How can I use pivot for three different column(col1,col2,col3)? I am not that much good at oracle. Can you please give me one example so that i can follow the same

Comment: Why doesn't the second row of output end in 98 and not 41?

Comment: sorry that was a typo. i corrected it in the post.

Comment: OK. And I think the 36 in the next to last row last column should be 19? I think I have a possible solution if that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, you need use `ROW_NUMBER` function with *windows function* in subquery make the row number in `sales_rev_asset` table. then do `unpivot` in `sales_lab`,then `join` by the row number.

```
CREATE TABLE sales_rev_asset(
  salesid        INT,
  year           INT,
  rev_ratio1     INT,
  rev_ratio_2    INT,
  ratio_3        INT,
  asset_ratio1   INT,
  asset_ratio_2  INT,
  asset_ratio_3  INT
);


INSERT INTO    sales_rev_asset VALUES (10001,2016,30,12,56,78,89,90);
INSERT INTO    sales_rev_asset VALUES (10001,2017,13,56,87,33,95,28);
INSERT INTO    sales_rev_asset VALUES (10001,2018,98,84,53,62,24,48);
INSERT INTO    sales_rev_asset VALUES (10002,2016,33,55,62,69,78,10);
INSERT INTO    sales_rev_asset VALUES (10002,2017,62,17,12,14,7 ,9);
INSERT INTO    sales_rev_asset VALUES (10002,2018,28,83,45,16,35,50);


CREATE TABLE sales_lab(
  salesid     INT,
  ratio_name  VARCHAR(50),
  col1     INT,
  col2    INT,
  col3     INT
);

INSERT INTO sales_lab VALUES (10001,'lab_ratio1',1,15,54);
INSERT INTO sales_lab VALUES (10001,'lab_ratio2',3,54,41);
INSERT INTO sales_lab VALUES (10001,'lab_ratio3',5,98,12);
INSERT INTO sales_lab VALUES (10002,'lab_ratio1',2,74,23);
INSERT INTO sales_lab VALUES (10002,'lab_ratio2',8,32,36);
INSERT INTO sales_lab VALUES (10002,'lab_ratio3',9,19,65);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with cte as (
  select t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY salesid ORDER BY salesid) rn 
  from sales_lab t
),unpivot_CTE as (
   select t.SALESID,
           1 RN,
          (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio1' and rn = 1  then col1 end) AS lab_ratio1,
          (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio2' and rn = 2  then col1 end) AS lab_ratio2,
          (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio3' and rn = 3  then col1 end) AS lab_ratio3
    from cte t
    UNION ALL
    select t.SALESID,
           2 RN,
           (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio1' and rn = 1  then col2 end),
           (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio2' and rn = 2  then col2 end),
           (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio3' and rn = 3  then col2 end)
    from cte t
    UNION ALL
    select t.SALESID,
           3 RN,
           (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio1' and rn = 1  then col3 end),
           (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio2' and rn = 2  then col3 end),
           (Case when t.RATIO_NAME = 'lab_ratio3' and rn = 3  then col3 end)
    from cte t
)
select t1.*,t2.lab_ratio1,t2.lab_ratio2,t2.lab_ratio3
from (
  select t.*,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY salesid ORDER BY year) rn 
  from sales_rev_asset t
) t1
INNER JOIN (
   select 
      SALESID,
      rn,
      MAX(lab_ratio1)  lab_ratio1,
      MAX(lab_ratio2)  lab_ratio2,
      MAX(lab_ratio3)  lab_ratio3
   from unpivot_CTE
   group by SALESID,rn
) t2 ON t1.salesid = t2.salesid and t1.rn = t2.rn
ORDER BY t1.SALESID,t1.year
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/167e2/7/0)**:

```
| SALESID | YEAR | REV_RATIO1 | REV_RATIO_2 | RATIO_3 | ASSET_RATIO1 | ASSET_RATIO_2 | ASSET_RATIO_3 | RN | LAB_RATIO1 | LAB_RATIO2 | LAB_RATIO3 |
|---------|------|------------|-------------|---------|--------------|---------------|---------------|----|------------|------------|------------|
|   10001 | 2016 |         30 |          12 |      56 |           78 |            89 |            90 |  1 |          1 |          3 |          5 |
|   10001 | 2017 |         13 |          56 |      87 |           33 |            95 |            28 |  2 |         15 |         54 |         98 |
|   10001 | 2018 |         98 |          84 |      53 |           62 |            24 |            48 |  3 |         54 |         41 |         12 |
|   10002 | 2016 |         33 |          55 |      62 |           69 |            78 |            10 |  1 |          2 |          8 |          9 |
|   10002 | 2017 |         62 |          17 |      12 |           14 |             7 |             9 |  2 |         74 |         32 |         19 |
|   10002 | 2018 |         28 |          83 |      45 |           16 |            35 |            50 |  3 |         23 |         36 |         65 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pivot the `sales_lab` using this code:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT salesid, ratio_name, col1
  FROM sales_tab
  WHERE conditions
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(col1)
  FOR ratio_name
  IN ( lab_ratio1, lab_ratio2, lab_ratio3)
)
```

That will give you the output as you want it, then you can use a simple JOIN using salesid to display the data as you requested.

Comment: I am trying the above on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/499fe8/17
and getting the below error

"ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values"

Comment: Use single quotes for the IN sentences ('lab_ratio1','lab_ratio2'...) etc

Comment: I am not getting the expected result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/499fe8/31
In the pivot we use only col1 that's why only col1 data is showing

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/499fe8/48

That's what you want... but here's the thing, while doing the pivot, you can retrieve only 1 `lab_ratio`row per `salesid` because you don't have `year` on the other table, check the fiddle and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
create table pivoted as
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT salesid,2016 year, ratio_name, col1
  FROM sales_lab
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(col1)
  FOR ratio_name
  IN ( 'lab_ratio1' lab_ratio1, 'lab_ratio2' lab_ratio2, 'lab_ratio3' lab_ratio3)
)
union
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT salesid,2017 year, ratio_name, col2
  FROM sales_lab
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(col2)
  FOR ratio_name
  IN ( 'lab_ratio1' lab_ratio1, 'lab_ratio2' lab_ratio2, 'lab_ratio3' lab_ratio3)
)
union
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT salesid,2018 year, ratio_name, col3
  FROM sales_lab
)
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(col3)
  FOR ratio_name
  IN ( 'lab_ratio1' lab_ratio1, 'lab_ratio2' lab_ratio2, 'lab_ratio3' lab_ratio3)
);

select
s.salesid,
s.year,
s.rev_ratio1,
s.rev_ratio_2,
s.ratio_3,
s.asset_ratio1,
s.asset_ratio_2,
s.asset_ratio_3,
p.lab_ratio1,
p.lab_ratio2,
p.lab_ratio3
from 
sales_rev_asset s
join
pivoted p
on
  s.salesid = p.salesid and
  s.year = p.year
order by
s.salesid,
s.year;
```

Output:

```
   SALESID       YEAR REV_RATIO1 REV_RATIO_2    RATIO_3 ASSET_RATIO1 ASSET_RATIO_2 ASSET_RATIO_3 LAB_RATIO1 LAB_RATIO2 LAB_RATIO3
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ------------- ------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
     10001       2016         30          12         56           78            89            90          1          3          5
     10001       2017         13          56         87           33            95            28         15         54         98
     10001       2018         98          84         53           62            24            48         54         41         12
     10002       2016         33          55         62           69            78            10          2          8          9
     10002       2017         62          17         12           14             7             9         74         32         19
     10002       2018         28          83         45           16            35            50         23         36         65
```